# Issue with creating a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a WordPress theme and I used the following code to insert the functionality for adding feature images but it does not work. There is no error but whenever I try uploading an image it gets stuck on crunching and never gets completed and sometimes gives an error try again later some error occurred .

```
//theme support
function wpb_theme_setup(){
//nav menu
    register_nav_menus(array(
      'primary' => __('Primary Menu')
    ));

//feature images on posts
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}
//for the above function to work we need tocreate an addaction function, which lets us choose a hook to run it
//the one we want is aftr set up theme

  add_action('after_setup_theme','wpb_theme_setup');
```

Please correct if I am doing something wrong 
thank you

Comment: Please do not add unrelated tags. Although Wordpress is written using `php`, this is not a `php` question.

Comment: i am sorry , i am new here.

Answer (score 1):

Your COde is fine. Change the permission setting of the image folder where the images are being saved.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that ?

Comment: Use This in your terminal.
find /localhost/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
where localhost/htdocs is the path... It can vary in your system.
If you are a mac user you can simply go the the image folder.. right click the folder and cilck get info.. on the bottom there is permission options

Comment: i don't know how to use the terminal and i am using windows . any other way i could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Enter that just like this in your functions.php (without the wrapping function)

```
// Allow post thumbnails

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 


// Register navigation

register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Menu' );
```

Comment: What is the problem with wrapping function?

Comment: even if i keep it outside of a wrapping function the problem still persists

Comment: @Trix: its just not necessary. And why should anyone want to unhook that.

Comment: @user2296604: Probably the problem is not your theme support but the image upload. WordPress can't manage images of a certain size (depeding on the server). Have you tried to upload smaller images (1000x1000px)?

Comment: yes tried all sorts of images and its being done on localhost